# Quicksort with 2 way partitioning

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement `quicksort` algorithm by `Sadgewick`. The code was taken from here http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/static/QuicksortIsOptimal.pdf

Here is what was in the book:

```
void quicksort(Item a[], int l, int r)
{ 
   int i = l-1, j = r; Item v = a[r];

   if (r <= l) return;

   for (;;)
   {
      while (a[++i] < v) ;

      while (v < a[--j]) if (j == l) break;

      if (i >= j) break;

      exch(a[i], a[j]);
   }

   exch(a[i], a[r]);
   quicksort(a, l, i-1);
   quicksort(a, i+1, r);
}
```

And here is my implementation in `C#`:

```
static void QuickSort2Partitions(int[] a, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left - 1, j = right;
    var v = a[right];

    if (right <= left)
        return;

    while(true)
    {
        while (a[++i] < v) ;
        while(v < a[--j])
        {
            if (j == left)
                break;
        }
        if (i >= j)
            break;

        var c1 = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = c1;
    }

    var c2 = a[i];
    a[i] = a[right];
    a[right] = c2;

    QuickSort2Partitions(a, left, i - 1);
    QuickSort2Partitions(a, i + 1, right);
}
```

I am trying to call it like:

```
var a = new int[10] { 9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 0 };
QuickSort2Partitions(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
```

But for the very first recursive call it passes `-1` as `right` and this code is throwing an `out of range exception`:

```
var v = a[right];
```

since `right is -1`. If I change in debug to `0` then process continues and ends with correct output.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: The error is in: quicksort(a, l, i-1); in combiantion with int i = l-1

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič, I have tried with various combinations of int i = l-1  and quicksort(a, l, i-1), {l, i},{l-1,i}{l+1,i}{l,i-1}... But everytime I am getting stackoverflow or outofrange exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the call to

```
var v = a[right];
```

after the line

```
if (right <= left)
    return;
```

Comment: Oh, Sadgewick! This corrects the situation, but I wonder if this is the error in the book?

Comment: It seams that the algorithm without modification works except for the combination of items where min of array is the last element of array :) I think Sadgewick just missed that and didn't correct the code in book.

Comment: Seems more like a mistake in the book imho. In C (which it seems to be) this is undefined behavior.